# Laravel WhereIn Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Why does this return a collection as expected;

```
$postcodes = DB::table('payments')->whereIn('VendorZIP', array('BS19AA','PO48AA'))->get();
print_r($postcodes);
```

But this returns an error;

```
$payments = Payment::all();
$payments->whereIn('VendorZIP', array('BS19AA','PO48AA'))->get();
print_r($payments);
```

The error is;

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereIn()
```

Of course I have a Payment model;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Payment extends Model {
    //
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to call `all()` before `whereIn()`. Change your code to this:

```
$payments = Payment::whereIn('VendorZIP', array('BS19AA','PO48AA'))->get();
```

You can find more examples in [Eloquent basic usage](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage) documentation.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work on a relationship

Comment: I have followed you exactly but am still getting one record while when I use it's mysql query in phpmyadmin, it returns 2 records which is correct. Your suggestion returns me only one record. It does not work for me. Thanks.